# Aligning a Linear Layout within a RelativeLayout to the Center and to the Left

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Currently I have tried aligning my Linear Layout to the left and center but currently cannot get this to work. See code below:

```
    CustomLinearLayout sideMenu = new CustomLinearLayout(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams sideMenuParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    sideMenuParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    sideMenuParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);   

    sideMenu.setLayoutParams(sideMenuParams);   
    sideMenu.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sideMenu.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    sideMenu.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    //sideMenu.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    sideMenu.addView(AppSoups);
    sideMenu.addView(salads);
    sideMenu.addView(ribs);
    sideMenu.addView(favorites);
    sideMenu.addView(sandwiches);
    sideMenu.addView(sides);
    sideMenu.addView(desserts);

    RelativeLayout screenLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    screenLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    screenLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.body_bkgd);
    screenLayout.addView(sideMenu);

    setContentView(screenLayout);
```

CustomLinearLayout is just a class that extends LinearLayout to do some custom drawing. Anyway what I am doing wrong here? So far it aligns left and to the top of the relative layout but i cannot get it to center. Just as a side note both or either or of my rules do not work in conjuction with setting the LinearLayout to the center(i have it commented out in the code). Finally the views that i am adding to the linear layout are just textviews - just FYI(code not shown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are "overriding the layout params you've set in line 5 with new layout params you are setting in line 7, so

```
    sideMenuParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    sideMenuParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
```

are not really taking affect

Comment: thank you that did it! I guess things might get a lot more complicated once you start having relative layout children and inside that more layout of different types. As a side note i had to change my sideMenuParams to WRAP content because it was filling up the whole relative layout screen horizontally.

Comment: always glad to help.  I recommend you to avoid from define layout by code. unless you have a really good reason - use the xml layout files

Comment: well other than keeping up my java skills, i have many layouts that I create dynamically(at run time) that can change form during the course of the app, dependent on a variety of events. thanks again for the help. Oh yeah turns out i didnt need both of those rules. CENTER_VERTICAL was enough to do the job.

Comment: that's exactly the only good reason I can think of defining layout in code. :)

Comment: well you could argue that keeping up java skills is also necessary - especially since many android jobs out there want you to be able to code in java..but i get your point and agree :)

Answer (score 1):

In here

```
screenLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

try changing the WRAP_CONTENT to FILL_PARENT